# Having toruble while trying to display/hide elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was struggling with this for few hours and couldn't make it right.
Is it possible to write jquery code for this so when `<span>` is clicked it would do this:

1. Search if any of `<p>` is already displayed (`display:block`) and if so, hide them all, if not, find closest `<p>` of that `<span>` and display it.
2. If you click on `<span>` whose child (`<p>`) is already active, hide it instead of displaying it

U can check my fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rk8sgqc5/1/)  or see my code bellow:
**HTML**

```
    <div>
    <span>First</span>
    <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div>
    <span>Second</span>
    <p>2</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    display:inline-block; 
    padding:8px;
    background:skyblue;
    color:white;
    font-family:helvetica;
    cursor:pointer;
}
div{
    display:inline-block; 
}
p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('span').click(function(){
  $('p').not($(this).next()).hide();
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ovh0h9q/)**